# Cellular proxy resizing images?

Tags: image, proxy

Ive noticed recently that two of my wireless providers (freedompop which uses sprint, and net10 which uses at&t) seem to be using some sort of content proxy which is resizing my website images and making them look quite poor. As a test i connected to both of these wireless services and loaded a page through their connection, and then again through a vpn. Both times through the cell services themselves an example image downloaded and was only 9kb, however the actual jpeg is 30kb. The image looks poor and grainy after being recompressed. Over vpn, i got the full size image so this seems to be pointing to the cell carrier using some kind of proxy to reduce their bandwidth.

Has anyone else noticed this recently and is there anything we can do to keep our images looking good, or instruct the proxy not to resize?

Answer (score 0):

Did a little more research and did a few different tests. What I found is that the proxies the carriers are using (at least my two) are only capable of downsizing jpegs. I tried png files through both of my services, and neither one got resized. So if you want to preserve the quality of your images, even for people on a cellular connection it seems that using PNG's might be a start, at least for now until the proxies are capable of downsizing PNG's too.